# Using parameters in Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, api, filter, parameters

Guys please let me know if I am not being clear in my question below.

I have an XML file that looks like this (data.xml):

```
<row>
    <JUDGE>ABC</JUDGE>
    <REGION>06</REGION>
</row>
<row>
    <JUDGE>XYZ</JUDGE>
    <REGION>05</REGION>
</row>
```

What I am trying to do is build a JQuery to get this file and place it in a table. So far this has been successful.

The next step is to use something like this (basically an API):

www.blahblahblah.com/data/?REGION=05

When typing this in the browser I should be able to get the following result:

```
<row>
    <JUDGE>XYZ</JUDGE>
    <REGION>05</REGION>
</row>
```

Again, please let me know if any more clarification needed from my end and I appreciate your help!

Comment: _"When typing this in the browser I should be able to get the following result:"_ Is expected result that only `<row>
    <JUDGE>XYZ</JUDGE>
    <REGION>05</REGION>
</row>` should be displayed if `location.href` is  `www.blahblahblah.com/data/?REGION=05` ? `<REGION>05</REGION>` should not be displayed ?

Comment: @Stryner: My question is how to get the values using the URL. I am not usinig URL routing

Comment: _"My question is how to get the values "_ What does "get" mean ?

Comment: @guest271314: When typing the REGION=05 I should be able to see the XML row/rows containing the 05 value in the Region tag

Comment: _"When typing the REGION=05 I should be able to see the XML row/rows containing the 05 value in the Region tag "_ Other values should not be displayed ?

Comment: @guest271314 correct no other values should be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `location.search` , `.split()` with parameter `"="` , `.hide()` , `.filter()` , `.show()` .

```
$(function() {
  var items = location.search.split("=")[1];
  $("row").hide()
  .filter(function() {
     // convert `REGION` text `"05"` to `Number` `5` for strict equality check
     return +($(this).find("REGION").text()) === +(items)
  })
  .show()
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2eo3mmx8/2/